# Why can't I view an image on a mobile device?

Tags: support, images

How can I view an image on a mobile device?

For example, I want to ask a question. I upload an image for the reference in my question. I post the question, and the image will appear. But when I am trying to see the question on mobile or Stack Exchange/Overflow apps, it shows nothing, not even the description of the image.

I used the default format like this (picture is just an example):

[image]

When I am trying to view the image above on my mobile device, it shows nothing.

What is the correct format to view an image that we have uploaded to our posts?

Here what it looks like on my Android:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Is it by any chance a browser like Opera or Chrome with their image compression proxy (data saver, Opera Turbo, etc.) enabled? Or perhaps a browser that doesn't show alt text where it should?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should just work, assuming it uploads (I've done pngs, jpeg and gif, and there's a maximum file size), and both the web page and mobile app scale it as necessary.

A [quick google search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=telcomsel%20imgur&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=L3--WYL2D8T5vgTCw7aADQ) suggests your phone company - Telkomsel has blocked imgur in the past. I'd try seeing if it works over wifi (with a different ISP?) or to try a proxy (I often use tunnelbear's free tier and app) to test.

Works for me in the mobile website on chrome

[image]

And in the app on android.

[image]

I suspect if it's not working, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I confirm I see it on my iosapp too

Comment: i have updated my question @Journeyman Geek

Comment: I'd suggest the problem lies elsewhere - maybe your ISP's blocking imgur?

Comment: you are right... i cant acces imgur. okay that's what i wanted to know. and thanks for your answer @JourneymanGeek

Comment: telkomsel's apparently blocked imgur in the past so... yeah, looks even more likely.

Comment: In theory, a blocked image should still show the alt text. Assuming the poster hasn't removed the default text and left nothing there.

Comment: Pretty sure SE dosen't alt text by default.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The `enter image description here` you get when you insert an image with the upload tool is rendered as alt text.

Comment: The image sure did load the alt text, in my ss image upthere, the page didnt completely loaded, so thats why alt text didnt shown up